# Loop through random numbers

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to spread 8 balls on the stage with an uneven space between them within a range. using  `myNum` variable in this statement `ball.x = 150 + i * myNum;` inside `for` loop I was hopping that it will spread each of the 8 balls in an uneven space. However this is not what's happening, instead it position 8 balls with an even space and then about a minute later it positions another set of 8 balls with different spacing.

```
var minLimit: int = 25;
var maxLimit: int = 43;
var range: int = maxLimit - minLimit;
var myNum: Number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minLimit;

var balls: Array = [],
  ball: bomb30a;

for (var i: int = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  ball = new bomb30a();
  ball.x = 150 + i * myNum;
  ball.y = 242;
  balls.push(ball);
  addChild(ball);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code defines a random number `myNum`, then loops 8 times. Why would `myNum` change in the middle of the loop?

If you want each iteration in the loop to use a different random number, you need to move the random number code into the loop so it gets executed on each iteration.

```
ball.x = 150 + i * (Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minLimit);
```